# Parallelizing a fitness function in genetic algorithm

Tags: java, concurrency, genetic-algorithm

I'm beginner to Java and as my homework I'm supposed to implement concurrency to genetic algorithm solution for Travelling Salesman Problem posted [here](http://www.theprojectspot.com/tutorial-post/applying-a-genetic-algorithm-to-the-travelling-salesman-problem/5). Our goal is to make chromosome evaluation performed by threads. So my guess is I have to rewrite this part of code to be multithreaded:

```
// Gets the best tour in the population
public Tour getFittest() {
    Tour fittest = tours[0];
    // Loop through individuals to find fittest
    for (int i = 1; i < populationSize(); i++) {
        if (fittest.getFitness() <= getTour(i).getFitness()) {
            fittest = getTour(i);
        }
    }
    return fittest;
}

// Gets population size
public int populationSize() {
    return tours.length;
}
```

Originaly I intended on manually splitting the Array beetwen threads but I believe it;s not the best solution to the problem. So I made some research and everyone suggest to use either parallel streams or ExecutorService. However I had trouble applying both of this solutions even thought I tried to emulate examples posted in other threads. So my questions are: how exactly do I implement them in this case and which one is faster?

Edit: Sorry, I forget to post solution I've tried. Here it is:

```
public Tour getFittest() {
    Tour fittest = tours[0];
    synchronized (fittest) {
        final ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(4); 
        final List<Future<?>> futures = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i = 1; i < populationSize(); i++) {
            Future<?> future = executor.submit((Runnable) () -> {
                if (fittest.getFitness() <= getTour(i).getFitness()) {
                    fittest = getTour(i);
                }
            });
            futures.add(future);
        }
        try {
            for (Future<?> future : futures) {
                future.get();
            }
        }catch (InterruptedException | ExecutionException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    return fittest;
}
public int populationSize() {
    return tours.length;
}
```

However when trying to run it I receive "Local variable fittest defined in an enclosing scope must be final or effectively final" error at line:

```
fittest = getTour(i);
```

And I have no clue why it's happening or how can I fix it as adding final keyword while initializing it does not fix it. Other than that I have some doubts about using synchronized keyword in this solution. I believe that to achieve true multithreading I need to make use on it due to resource being shared by various threads. Am I right? Sadly I didn't saved my attemp at using streams but I have trouble understanding how it works at all.

Edit2: I managed to "fix" my solution by adding two workarounds. Currently my code looks like that:

```
public Tour getFittest() {
    Tour fittest = tours[0];
    synchronized (fittest) {
        final ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(4); 
        final List<Future<?>> futures = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i = 1; i < populationSize(); i++) {
            final Integer innerI = new Integer(i);
            Future<?> future = executor.submit((Runnable) () -> {
                if (fittest.getFitness() <= getTour(innerI).getFitness()) {
                    setFitness(innerI, fittest);
                    }
                }
            );
            futures.add(future);
        }
        try {
            for (Future<?> future : futures) {
                future.get();
            }
        }catch (InterruptedException | ExecutionException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        }
    return fittest;
}

public int populationSize() {
    return tours.length;
}

public Tour setFitness (int i, Tour fittest) {
        fittest = getTour(i);
        return fittest;
}
```

That said, while it's compiling, there are two problems. Memory usage keeps rising every second the program runs, maxing out my 16GB of RAM in like ten seconds while variable 'fittest' does not change at all. So I guess I'm still doing something wrong.

Comment: Show your attempts at achieving your goal first

Comment: here is an [article](https://blog.overops.com/forkjoin-framework-vs-parallel-streams-vs-executorservice-the-ultimate-benchmark/) about efficiencies

Comment: your variable i is updated during the loop process, this means it's changing and is not effectively final.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my steams implementation:

```
private static Tour getFittest(Tour[] tours){
    List<Map.Entry<Tour,Double>> lengths = new ArrayList<>();
    Arrays.stream(tours).parallel().forEach(t->lengths.add(new AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<Tour,Double>(t,t.getLength())));
    return Collections.min(lengths,Comparator.comparingDouble(Map.Entry::getValue)).getKey();
}
```

Upon further looking can be 1liner kinda depending on your definition

```
    private static Tour getFittest(Tour[] tours) {

    return Arrays.stream(tours).parallel().map(t -> new AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<Tour, Double>(t, t.getLength()))
            .min(Comparator.comparingDouble(Map.Entry::getValue)).get().getKey();
}
```

also after further looking they use .getFitness() which is reciprocal of length. if you use that then use .max() as the filter.

actually even better after review

```
 return Arrays.stream(tours).parallel()
            .min(Comparator.comparingDouble(Tour::getLength)).get();
```

Comment: What is getLength() function supposed to do? Eclipse wants me to create it in order to compile.

Comment: getLength is a method i wrote in the class. looking back at the GA article the method is actually `getDistance()`, but as mentioned you can use `getFitness()`  with `max` which is a method on `Tour` also.